# LoadError on Windows when trying to generate a model

Tags: padrino, ruby-datamapper

When trying to generate a model in a new Padrino project, I get the following:

```
C:\temp\ruby\test>padrino g model client
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.13-x86-mingw32/lib/do_sqlite
3.rb:32:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby1
93/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.13-x86-mingw32/lib/do_sqlite3/1.9/do
_sqlite3.so (LoadError)
```

I have done `bundle install` successfully prior to trying this generation. The .so file mentioned in the error is present.

I am running on Windows 7 64 bit, but the version I have is 32 (which I assume is OK, right?)

ruby -v is ruby `1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `sqlite3.dll` to `C:\Ruby193\bin`